# How do I code a discord bot so it becomes able to post modified gif and/or png profile picture using python PIL?

Tags: python, discord, python-imaging-library, gif

This code works with users that have `.png` format in their profile pictures, however, when it comes to users that have `.gif` animated profile pictures, the code does not work. It gives this error `OSError(f"cannot write mode {mode} as PNG") from e OSError: cannot write mode PA as PNG`

I attempted to change all `.png` to `.gif` but I still had trouble.

`ValueError: image has wrong mode`

This is the aforementioned code that ***only works*** with `.png` format.

```py
class avatar(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        guild = self.client.get_guild(GUILD_ID)
        general_channel = guild.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)


        url = requests.get(member.avatar_url)
        avatar = Image.open(BytesIO(url.content))
        avatar = avatar.resize((285,285));
        bigsize = (avatar.size[0] * 3,  avatar.size[1] * 3)
        mask = Image.new('L', bigsize, 0)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
        draw.ellipse((0, 0) + bigsize, fill=255)
        mask = mask.resize(avatar.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        avatar.putalpha(mask)

        output = ImageOps.fit(avatar, mask.size, centering=(1420, 298))
        output.putalpha(mask)
        output.save('avatar.png')

        img = Image.open('welcomealpha.png')
        img.paste(avatar,(1408,265), avatar)
        img.save('wel.png')

        file = discord.File('wel.png')
        channel = self.client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
        await channel.send(file=file)
        guild = self.client.get_guild(GUILD_ID)
        channel = guild.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
```

Could it be that the bot doesn't know how to discern between `.gif` & `.png` ? If that's the case, what would be the most efficient way for the bot to *recognize* which profile picture format each new user has in order to manipulate image/gif accordingly to its format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear here: Your original `Image` object has [mode](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#modes) `P`, i.e. it's a palettised image. When adding an alpha channel as you did, you get mode `PA`. As Pillow tells you, saving `Image` objects with mode `PA` as `PNG` is not supported. Since you only want to save to some static `PNG` without any animation, I assume it's save to convert the `Image` object to mode `RGB` right in the beginning, such that you get a `RGBA` mode `Image` object in the end, which can be saved as `PNG` without any problems.

I took the following excerpt from your code and added the conversion to mode `RGB`:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageOps

avatar = Image.open('homer.gif').convert('RGB')
avatar = avatar.resize((285, 285))
bigsize = (avatar.size[0] * 3,  avatar.size[1] * 3)
mask = Image.new('L', bigsize, 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
draw.ellipse((0, 0) + bigsize, fill=255)
mask = mask.resize(avatar.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
avatar.putalpha(mask)

output = ImageOps.fit(avatar, mask.size, centering=(1420, 298))
output.putalpha(mask)
output.save('avatar.png')
```

The `GIF` input is Homer; the corresponding `Image` object has mode `P`:

[image: Homer]

The exported `PNG` is the following; it seems to be the first frame of the `GIF`:

[image: Output]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
Pillow:        8.1.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: First and foremost I would like to thank you for the time taken to answer my question! 

This helps a lot with the issue in regards to the first issue which was that the bot would not respond to the image.

Would it be possible to code the Discord Bot & Pillow in such way where it's able to discern between ``.gif`` and ``.png`` file?

The idea here is to have two outputs — If the user avatar is a ``.gif``, then the final output image is a gif so his/her's avatar can be animated.

If the user's avatar is a ``.png`` therefore its output is png.

Thank you so much for the reply!

Comment: To distinguish between `PNG` and `GIF` would be quite easy. Just check `avatar.format` after loading. Nevertheless, processing a `GIF` including resizing, adding a custom alpha channel / transparency will be much more difficult than for a static `PNG`. There's plenty of Q&As on that topic.